# iPhone app starts with window 20 (or so) pixels high

Tags: iphone, viewcontroller

every time i begin building an app the main screen starts out with a white bar at the bottom of the screen. It is only on the main view controller and if i switch to another view and then back to the view the white bar is not there... why does this happen? I think it has to do with how i implement the view in the appDelegate... here is how i implement it:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    

// Override point for customization after application launch.
StartUpScreen *main = [[StartUpScreen alloc] initWithNibName:@"StartUpScreen" bundle:nil];
self.viewController = main;
[window addSubview:main.view];
[main release];
[window makeKeyAndVisible];


return YES;
```

If you need more details just let me know. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if this will fix the issue you are describing but you should do:

```
window.rootViewController = main;
```

Instead of:

```
[window addSubview:main.view];
```